# spring boot error The system cannot find the specified file

Tags: spring-boot

my properties in:
---resources
-------parkSpace.properties
and,I used FileInputStream to read the prpperties:

```
public static Map<String,String> get(){
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("parkSpace.properties"));
}
```

why occurred  'the system cannot find the path'?
ths.

Comment: need more information - are you running this code "exploded" (*.class files unpacked) or are you running from a packaged jar?

Comment: I just run the start Class,not running from a packaged jar,but,I still fond the error when I runningthe packaged jar

Answer (score 2):

You should get the resource from classloader, using `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String name)` instead.

With spring frmework, Spring’s `Resource` interface is meant to be a more capable interface for abstracting access to low-level resources.

**Reference**

[Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html).

Comment: i still can't find my properties,and I find some codes:`Properties propFlies = new Properties();propFlies.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/parkSpace.properties"));`can get my properties,but what I really want is get the properties when I first run my project only,and,in static method,the above codes can not effect.

Comment: @Y.yi you should get classloader